# Chart.js misreading arrays for labels and axes

Tags: node.js, chart.js

**My problem:**
My charts.js graph is not displaying correctly. I am passing in arrays for the axis labels, x-values, and y-values, but the values are not displaying correctly on the screen.

In the y-axis labels, the system treats every letter as an entry, instead of treating every element in the array as a column.

In the data, it inserts zero values without a clear reason why. Here is a comparison graph showing what it should look like and what it actually looks like:

It should look like this
[image]

Actually looks like this
[image]

Overarching structure: this is a node.js/MySQL app using the express framework and EJS as the view engine. I'm using sequelize is my ORM.

Specific issues:

- x-labels (defined by an array of strings) incorrectly treat every letter as an element.
- After the first two data entries, three entries of blank data are inserted; it is unclear why

**What I have tried**:

1. I console.logged all the arrays I'm passing through on the page load to make sure they are appearing correctly (they are). [here is a screenshot from the terminal of labels and the 2 data series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaxxg.png)
2. I copied and pasted the arrays from the terminal directly into the ejs. This worked([it is how I got this comparison screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jSgW.png)).
3. I confirmed the datatypes of the arrays in the callback function (they are all arrays, which is correct).

**My code**:

1. The route

```js
const   express     = require("express"),
        router      = express.Router({mergeParams: true}),
        moment      = require("moment"),
        charts      = require("chart.js"),
        Bookkeeping = require("../src/models/bookkeeping"),
        User        = require("../src/models/user");

const errorHandler = (err) => {
    console.error("whoooa there cowboy: ", err)
};

//================================================================================
//show
//================================================================================
router.get("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const   entryDate   = [],
                sales       = [],
                costs       = [],
                profit      = [];
        //finding user based off id in request
        let user = await User.findByPk(req.params.id);

        //finding all bookkeeping data for this user
        let bookkeeping = await Bookkeeping.findAll({
            where: {
              user_teleg_id: user.user_teleg_id
            }
        });

        //logging sales into array
        let n = 1
        bookkeeping.forEach((entry) => {
            entryDate.push("Week " + n)
            sales.push(entry.dataValues.week_sales)
            costs.push(entry.dataValues.week_cost_total)
            profit.push(entry.dataValues.profit)
            n ++
        });

        res.render("users/showBookeeping", {
            user: user,
            entryDate: entryDate,
            sales: sales,
            costs: costs,
            profit: profit,
            moment: moment});
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

2. The EJS file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Users Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="row">
              <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
              <script type="text/javascript">

                   const entryDate = "<%= entryDate %>"
                   const costs = "<%= costs %>"
                   const sales = "<%= sales %>"

                   const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                   const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                             labels: entryDate,
                             datasets: [{
                                  label: 'sales',
                                  data:  sales,
                                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                  borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                  borderWidth: 1
                             },
                             {
                                  label: "costs",
                                  data: costs,
                                  backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                                  borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                                  borderWidth: 1
                             }]

                         },
                         options: {
                             scales: {
                                  yAxes: [{
                                       ticks: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                       }
                                  }]
                             }
                         }
                    });
              </script>
         </div>
   </body>
```

Thank you very much for your help, and please let me know if there is any helpful info I left off!

Cheers

Comment: it does not help you at your problem, but here `forEach((entry, i)` you can get the index of the forEach loop, so you dont need `n` and you can write then `entryDate.push("Week " + i +1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky!

I see these lines in the `ejs` file

```
const entryDate = "<%= entryDate %>"
```

When this is actually rendered, it will run `toString()` against the value

```
['Week 1','Week 2','Week 3'].toString()
'Week 1,Week 2,Week 3'
```

And in the template its surrounding that `toString()` response in quotes:

```
const entryDate = "Week 1,Week 2,Week 3"
```

Since a string is just an array of characters it renders in that strange way.

Try doing this for the arrays in `ejs` instead:

```
const entryDate = <%- JSON.stringify(entryDate) %>
// also notice we removed the quotes! :)
```

This will run `JSON.stringify` against it, producting the string:

```
> JSON.stringify(['Week 1','Week 2','Week 3'])
'["Week 1","Week 2","Week 3"]'
```

So it will render like this:

```
const entryDate = ["Week 1","Week 2","Week 3"]
```

Do this for all your arrays and it should work!

Comment: Confirming this worked! Thanks so much for taking a look.